Is a $\mathcal B(R_+) \otimes \mathcal F $-jointly measurable process $X(t,\omega)$ measurable when restricted to $\mathcal B[0,T] \otimes F$
Let $X: (\mathbb R_+ \times \Omega, \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+) \otimes \mathcal F ) \rightarrow (\mathbb R_+, \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+))$ be a jointly measurable map. I would like to prove that the restriction of $X$ to the space $[0,T]\times \Omega$ is $\mathcal B[0,T] \otimes \mathcal F$ measurable as well. Is this true?
What I trie: Start with defining
$$ Y: ([0,T]\times \Omega, \mathcal B[0,T] \otimes \mathcal F) \rightarrow (\mathbb R_+, \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+)): \qquad Y(t,w)  = X(t,w),\quad \forall (t,\omega) \in [0,T]\times \Omega $$
and to try to prove $Y^{-1}(-\infty,b]$ is measurable. What I see is
$$ Y^{-1}(-\infty,b] = \{(t,\omega) \in [0,T]\times \Omega : X(t,w) \leq b \} = \Big([0,T]\times \Omega\Big) \cap X^{-1}(-\infty,b]  $$
and that $X^{-1}(-\infty,b] \in  \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+) \otimes \mathcal F$. But how do we conclude that  $Y^{-1}(-\infty,b] \in \mathcal B[0,T] \otimes \mathcal F$. Thank you for your help!

There's no filtration involved here... Also, I think the OP's question is true, and if we are talking about progressiveness (when a filtration is given) then it is not true for sure

Let me give a brief of an answer here (I will come back to check the details later):
We would like to prove something more general:
$$ \left( [0,T] \times \Omega \right) \cap \mathcal B(R_+) \otimes \mathcal F = \mathcal B[0,T] \otimes \mathcal F. $$
To see this, define the set
$$ \mathcal O:= \Big\{ S \in \mathcal B(R_+) \otimes \mathcal F \ \text{such that} \ \left( [0,T] \times \Omega \right) \cap S \in \mathcal B[0,T] \otimes \mathcal F \Big \} $$
Then one can prove that $\mathcal O$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal O = \mathcal B(R_+) \otimes \mathcal F $. From this the it follows $Y^{-1}(-\infty, b] \in  \mathcal B[0,T] \otimes \mathcal F $. It takes some more steps the show the equality of these $\sigma$-algebras, but I gess you can work out the details.
